# How to use RFHUTILC.EXE to connect to a remote queue manager

Tags: ibm-mq

I trying to connect RFHUTIL from my laptop to remote MQ server but its show error

09.43.47 Open for temporary reply queue failed rc=2035
Error getting queue names

Below are from Queue Manager Error Log:

```
2/26/2021 02:43:44 - Process(2716.35) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(MCP-50-50-1-5) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.1.0.7) QMgr(mq)
                      Time(2021-02-26T01:43:44.367Z)
                      RemoteHost(50.50.1.2)
                      CommentInsert1(g525097@mcp-50-50-1-5)
                      CommentInsert2(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE)
                      CommentInsert3(get)
                     
AMQ8077W: Entity 'g525097@mcp-50-50-1-5' has insufficient authority to access
object 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE'.

EXPLANATION:
The specified entity is not authorized to access the required object. The
following requested permissions are unauthorized: get
ACTION:
Ensure that the correct level of authority has been set for this entity against
the required object, or ensure that the entity is a member of a privileged
group.
```

Comment: Please can you look in the queue manager error log (found in MQ_DATA_PATH\qmgrs\<qmname>\errors\AMQERR01.LOG) and update your question with the error(s) you see in there at the time you received the 2035 reason code in RFHUTIL. With that information we will then be able to accurately help you with your issue.

Comment: Hi @Saravanan, I am having same problem connecting rfhutil to docker container mq. My java is able to connect though. Any suggestion please!!

Comment: @Saravanan you should follow Morag's suggestion, what you have provided so far is not enough to diagnose the issue.

Comment: The call to initialize the User ID 'G525097' failed with CompCode 2 and Reason
2035. If an MQCSP block was used, the User ID in the MQCSP block was ''. If a
userID flow was used, the User ID in the UID header was 'G525097' and any
CHLAUTH rules applied prior to user adoption were evaluated case-sensitively
against this value.

Comment: AMQ9557E: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed for 'G525097'.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the additional details, don't place logs in comments.   I works suggest you also mask any private information such as usernames.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any SYSTEM.*.SVRCONN channels?  Because CHLAUTH rules (on the queue manager) can be blocking you.

RFHUTILC uses your Windows UserId for authentication (MQ v8.0 or higher) and authorization for MQ objects (i.e. queue manager, channels, queues, etc.)

Did your MQAdmin give your UserId, or group which your UserId is in, permission to access the queue manager and the queues?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you have provided in your question, you need to run the following MQSC command (that is a command issued using the runmqsc tool). If you don't have full authority over this queue manager then I suggest you ask your MQ administrator to run this command. If you do have full authority over this queue manager then make sure you are running the runmqsc tool with the same user id that your started the queue manager with, and that you are running it on the machine where the queue manager resides.

```
SET AUTHREC PROFILE('SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE') OBJTYPE(QUEUE) GROUP(the-group-that-user-id-g525097-is-in) AUTHADD(GET)
```

If it still fails after you do this, please post the new error message because it will likely need other permissions and the error message, while similar, will be different.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run this command on queue manager and then try to access
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)

Comment: may i know which command and where should i run the command

Comment: ````runmqsc <<QMGR_NAME>> \n ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)````

Comment: runmqsc mq \n ALTER mq CHLAUTH(DISABLED) ---> like this....since my queue manager = mq

Comment: @SaravananSubramaniam...there are 2 commands...first is runmqsc mq- and then press enter...after that execute second command (copy paste it) ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)

Comment: AMQ8077W: Entity 'g525097@mcp-50-50-1-5' has insufficient authority to access
object 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE'.

Comment: can you please share the commands, how you have created queue manager

Comment: @Darshan this answer is absolutely a terrible suggestion to turn off security.  Instead of the user resolving the security issues properly, all you are doing is showing them a bad hack.  So, they will promote this bad hack into QA then PROD.  Companies already have enough security issues, we do not need to be promoting more security holes.

Comment: @Roger: I agree this is not a good suggestion...but I believe Saravanan is trying this on his local machine and not for any project in his company. Permissions/security which I asked him to turn off are generally taken care by MQ Admin person. No one would allow such things in their organization. Any change in security is also done via change request. To provide more suitable solution, Saravanan needs to share the Qmgr, channel definition.

Comment: @Darshan sure in a perfect world that is true but I have dealt with far, far too many customers that turn off security and never turn it back on.